# Is there a way to exclude already used characters from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

New to programming here, and I am just about to finish my first project-a password generator. I am trying to keep it as simple as possible, nothing fancy, yet I have come to a standstill. I want to implement an option that allows the user to only get one character to appear only once in the generated password. As of now, it is just a random jumble of characters, repeating and whatnot, so I was wondering if there is any way to implement such a feature-and if so, how? If statements? loops? I am up for all suggestions!

Here is the code.

```
var keys = {
    upperCase : ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"],
    lowerCase: ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","z"],
    number: ["0","1","2","3","5","6","7","8","9"],
    symbol: ["!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","+","~","|","}","{","[","]",":",";","?",">","<",",",".","/","-","="]
  }
  var getKey = [
    function upperCase() {
      return keys.upperCase[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.upperCase.length)];
    },
    function lowerCase() {
      return keys.lowerCase[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.lowerCase.length)];
    },
    function number() {
      return keys.number[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.number.length)];
    },
    function symbol() {
      return keys.symbol[Math.floor(Math.random() * keys.symbol.length)];
    }
  ];
  
  function createPassword() {
    var upper = document.getElementById("upperCase").checked;
    var lower = document.getElementById("lowerCase").checked;
    var number = document.getElementById("number").checked;
    var symbol = document.getElementById("symbol").checked;
    if (upper + lower + number + symbol === 0) {
      alert("Please check a box!");
      return;
    }
    var passwordBox = document.getElementById("passwordBox");
    var length = document.getElementById("length");
    var password = "";
    while (length.value > password.length) {
      var keyToAdd = getKey[Math.floor(Math.random() * getKey.length)];
      var isChecked = document.getElementById(keyToAdd.name).checked;
      if (isChecked) {
        password += keyToAdd();
      }
    }
    passwordBox.innerHTML = password;
  }
```

Link to codepen (with all HTML, JavaScript and CSS) is available [here](https://codepen.io/emblek/pen/eYyaqWw).

Comment: You did not show us your HTML

Answer (score 1):

@Embla I think this is what you are trying to achieve, let me know if smthg is missing in this solution. You didnt provide HTML, I just assumed what it might look like

```js
let passwordBox = document.getElementById("passwordBox");
  let length = document.getElementById("length");
 
const keys = {
    upperCase : ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"],
    lowerCase: ["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","z"],
    number: ["0","1","2","3","5","6","7","8","9"],
    symbol: ["!","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","_","+","~","|","}","{","[","]",":",";","?",">","<",",",".","/","-","="]
  }



function random( max, min=0){
   return ~~(Math.random() * (max - min) + min)
}

function getKey(objArr){
    const values = Object.values(objArr);
    const randValue = values[random(values.length)];
    return randValue[random(randValue.length)];
}


function createPassWord(passwordLength){
  const pwdStorage = new Set();
  while( pwdStorage.size < passwordLength ){
    pwdStorage.add(getKey(keys))
  }
  return [...pwdStorage].join('');
}

 
length.addEventListener('change', (event)=>{
  passwordBox.textContent = createPassWord(+length.value)
})
```

```css
input[type="number"]{
    width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left:10px;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<div class="password-Container">
        <h2 id="passwordBox">Password</h2>
    </div>
      <input type="number" name="" id="length" min="1" max="100" step="1" placeholder="Enter number">
```

Comment: @Waisu, you almost got it right! However, rather than creating a new generator, I am looking for an option to integrate into my already made one - an option that is re-reselectable to the user :) Sorry for not making that clear, as well as not includding the HTML.. I have now edited the post and linked a [codepen](https://codepen.io/emblek/pen/eYyaqWw) with all my code so far, if you want to check that out!

Answer (score -2):

I writed a function for your request, i hope that works for you.

```js
Array.prototype.getAndRemove = function (index) {
    const item = this[index];
    if (this.indexOf(item) > -1) {
        this = this.splice(this.indexOf(item), 1);
        if (this.indexOf(item) > -1) {
            this = this.splice(this.indexOf(item), 1);
        }
    }
    return item;
}
```

Comment: There's no good reason why `.getAndRemove()` should be available on the prototype of `Array` (especially not with `.splice()` being a thing)